# replace a character in a string in python

Tags: python

so I've got a grid like string that was made from .join'ing a list of lists:

```
grid_string = ["XXXXX", "X   X", "FFFFF"]
```

and now I want to replace the top left "X" in the grid with another character say like "Y" but if I do something like:

```
grid_string = grid_string.replace(grid_string[0], "Y")
```

it replaces every single "X" with "Y"

Comment: [``str.replace`` has an optional ``count`` argument.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Set it to 1 if you just want the first occurrence replaced.

Comment: `grid_string = grid_string.replace(grid_string[0][0], "Y")`